# Can Jomsocial professional component is working on localsystem?

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I want to integrate social networking features in my site and i was purchase jomsocial professional component from jomsocial website and i have one problem in there features list there where define 1 Domain
Support single installation

so i am not sure to install in my local system.

Comment: This is a question for the developer more than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Type in the domain that you will be using on your live site. You are still allowed to install on your localhost as it is for testing purposes. The extension doesn't deactivate once you have installed it for the first time ;)